# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, cursor, in-operator

Hy everybody

I have a cursor and I need to verify in where clause if a specific id belongs to an array.

However I haver an error

**android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT display_name, _id FROM view_data_restricted data WHERE (1) AND (data1 IN ? AND mimetype='vnd.android.cursor.item/group_membership' AND display_name like '%r%') ORDER BY display_name**

Here is my code

```
cursorContactosGrupos = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership._ID},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " IN ? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '%" + filter + "%'" ,
                new String[]{arrayTeste.toString().replace("[","(").replace("]",")")},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME
                );
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
cursorContactosGrupos = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership._ID},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " IN (?) AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "' AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '%" + filter + "%'" ,
                new String[]{arrayTeste.toString().replace("[","(").replace("]",")")},
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.DISPLAY_NAME
                );
```

Just enclose `?` with `(?)`

Because we write query as ...   `IN (VALUE)`